# How to set the value of TextView in application?

Tags: android, timer

Hi i want make a timer counter and i want the timer still counting and pause or stop when i click a button but now i can run the timer in app but i cannot set textView on fragment with the value of the timer

How can i set the text in text view ? so it will become a timer ?

here my code :

```
public class TimerFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private ImageView btnPause, btnStop, iconCreditInfo, iconStockOpname, iconOrder, iconReturn;
    private TextView timerValue, txtCreditInfo, txtStockOpname, txtOrder, txtReturn, namaClient, keterangan, dateValue;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    private float textSizeBig, imgSizeBig, textSizeSmall, imgSizeSmall;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);
        initialize();
        //start-time
         /*
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);*/
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  App.appInstance.startTimer();
                /*App app = ((App) getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                app.afficher();
                timerValue.setText(app.getTimer().toString());*/
            }
        });

        //make default icon and text size
        creditInfoDefault();
        orderDefault();
        stockOpnameDefault();
        returnDefault();

        //set today date
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        dateValue.setText(dateFormat.format(date).toString());


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    //    cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;

            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };


}
```

Here the app code :

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static App appInstance;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    private StringBuilder timer;

    public StringBuilder getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(StringBuilder timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appInstance = this;

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
    }

    public void afficher() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;

        timer.append("");
        timer.append(mins);
        timer.append(":");
        timer.append(String.format("%02d", secs));
       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),mins).show();
           /* timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs));*/
        customHandler.postDelayed((Runnable) this, 0);
      /*
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);*/
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        runnable.run();
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Did you check Chronometer ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html That could be helpful for what you are doing.

Comment: You can make the TextView static and access it through TimerFragment.timerValue. But the fragment should be visible otherwise you will get a crash.

Comment: where you want to set the text?? can you specify it properly? I find your question incomplete and vague

Answer (score 0):

You could use runOnUiThread.
I am assuming timerValue is your textView. 
Inside your Thread :

```
your_activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"+String.format("%02d",secs));
    }
});
```

Or you could use **Chronometer** widget. Check out this [tutorial](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/chronometer.php).